# How can i Assign value to char** inside structure

Tags: c

I  have a structure where I have char ** inside it , I have another pointer of type char * How can I assign value to it ? I tried strcpy() but it is giving me error argument of type "char **" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *".

```
struct tmp{

   char **ptr1;

   int x ; 

}

void foo( struct tmp *t, char *ptr){

   t->ptr1 = ptr;
 
   t->x = 0;

}
```

I tried with strcpy() but getting error
Can someone help  me out here .

Comment: It doesn't make sense to assign a `char*` to a `char**` so that would be why. What exactly are you trying to do, create an array of strings or what?

Comment: `t->ptr1 = &ptr;` of course. But does it do what you want? Because `ptr` gets destroyed when the function returns, and then `t->ptr1` points to a variable that was destroyed, and if you do `*t->ptr1` you are then accessing someone else's memory

Comment: No , it dosn't . actually I am using a third party api where structure has (char**) , but in my code value is of type char*. 
Also i am allocating char*ptr .

Comment: It's not enough to know the types. You need to know what exactly is meant to be contained, who is in charge of memory allocation and deallocation, etc. The API documentation should help with that.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Its a third party struct that i am using

Comment: @asdf1234 What does ptr1 **mean** - why is it in the structure, what is its purpose?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to alocate the space for the pointer.

```
void foo( struct tmp *t, char *ptr)
{
   t->ptr1 = malloc(sizeof(*t -> ptr1);
   *t->ptr1 = ptr;
   t->x = 0;
}
```

If you want to keep the copy of the string referenced by `ptr` you can

```
void foo( struct tmp *t, char *ptr)
{
   t->ptr1 = malloc(sizeof(*t -> ptr1));
   *t->ptr1 = strdup(ptr);
   t->x = 0;
}
```

or

```
void foo( struct tmp *t, char *ptr)
{
   t->ptr1 = malloc(sizeof(*t -> ptr1));
   *t->ptr1 = malloc(strlen(ptr) + 1);
   if(*t->ptr1) strcpy(*t->ptr1, ptr);
   t->x = 0;
}
```

or

```
void foo( struct tmp *t, char *ptr)
{
   size_t len = strlen(ptr);
   t->ptr1 = malloc(sizeof(*t -> ptr1));
   *t->ptr1 = malloc(len + 1);
   if(*t->ptr1) memcpy(*t->ptr1, ptr, len + 1);
   t->x = 0;
}
```

Comment: There's no way to know if this is what the structure is meant to contain from the information OP has given.

Comment: As the OP tried to use `strcpy` using `strlen(ptr)+1` might be more suitable but that's just guessing.

Comment: @Gerhardh happy now?